# i want to show interstitial ad on when some one press default back button on phone

Tags: javascript, android, html

I want to show interstitial ad on when some one open the post in my Webview and after press default back button on phone  then show the interstitial ads. Please help me to code with this. I don't know coding . I'm a student. Help to make this happen on my app. Tell me what I need to do. I put my `MainActivity.java` file.

```js
package com.sinhalagossip.Blogger.Tharu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://paththaramalli.info/");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
        {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength)
            {
                //download file using web browser
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: pls help me i dont know coding help me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

To handle when the back button is pressed, you need to override `onBackPressed` in your Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // other Activity stuff, like onCreate

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do stuff, like show the ad

        // call this if you want to let them go back
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

That said, if an app showed me an ad when I tried to go back, my next stop would be the Android settings to uninstall it...

Comment: pls can you edit my above code and paste it as code .i;m new to app development.pls help me sir

Comment: This goes in your Activity. Edited the answer to make that more clear.

Comment: sir i dont know how to do stuff and how to call this .pls i need when some one press back button show ads .pls edit commet like that.please

Comment: Help me pls i dont know coding. pls edit above code and put it here pls

Comment: help me my onBakcpressd lik this public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }